# bsd or posix way get preferred domain controller?

Tags: c, dns, posix, samba, bsd

Is there any way to get preferred domain controller name using BSD/POSIX C function calls?
Please, advice if there are any functions that can be used to get preferred DC name under Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Domain controllers aren't standardized in any way.  If you want to discover the domain controller, the best thing to do is find your target domain controller protocol and find it through this protocol using sockets.  For instance, windows domain controllers can be found using C# libraries, but in linux C you'd either have to get a 3rd party library or write the protocol out yourself.

Comment: Thank you for advice! But what about examples of such 3rd party libraries?

Comment: There is no POSIX definition of how to interact with a domain controller.  If you google LDAP C library though, you can get libraries for your desired LDAP architecture.